# How is the terrain displayed on the ND in a A320?

Tags: navigation, flight-instruments, radar

When you turn on "TERR ON ND" in a A320, you see terrain info on you navigation display (ND), but where does its source come from ?

- if data comes from FMGS stored inside its **memory**, then how come it cannot display it in all bounds of the display (see picture) ?

[image]

- if data comes from the nose **radar**, then how is it possible to see oceans when you're *on the ground* in an airport, say in JFK for example ? The radar beam would never be able to get to the water directly.

Comment: `how come it cannot display it in all bounds of the display (see picture) ?` uh? I've seen the picture, but I don't get what you mean with "all bounds of the display"

Comment: I mean like below the aircraft for example (and on the sides)

Comment: aircraft are non-holonomic systems, they can't move sideways and they can't pull back mid-air, so way waste precious screen real-estate for stuff that does not influence you?

Comment: On the sides, for better situational awareness, if you need to pull a steep turn

Comment: an A320 is not a fighter, its manoeuvrability is limited. you can be sure that they evaluated this when deciding exactly which angle to display

Comment: Matt, can you provide a link to the page containing the image (first for mandatory credit, and then for understanding the context)? This content is the EGPWS, based on an elevation map stored into the avionics, so water areas are identified. Colors depict *relative* altitudes. See page 429 of this [FCOM](http://nicmosis.as.arizona.edu:8000/ECLIPSE_WEB/TSE2015/A320_DOCUMENTS/A320-FCOM_DSC%20Aircraft%20Systems_part2.pdf).

Comment: Regarding the area displayed: The full 180° are only covered by the [recent versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3oRKmZ5qQg) of the EGPWS. the reason is likely that calculating relative altitudes is a heavy workload for the EGPWS CPU, and with new chips, more pixels can be computed in a decent time. See how slowly the display is refreshed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VfI4Pyam1E).

Comment: http://aircockpit.com/viewtopic.php?p=49417&sid=f4823eeafd9cfef861a0928e5cec1729

Comment: Ok, so I guess it is a misinterpretation when people talk about "radar", when it's actually already in the FMGS.

Comment: Not in the FMGS, the EGPWS is an alerting device, it doesn't actuate any control of the aircraft, it provides altimetry data and alarms that happen to be displayed on the same display than some navigational information from the flight computer. See [Gerry's answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31472/how-is-the-terrain-displayed-on-the-nd-in-a-a320#31481).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The terrain data is contained in a database within the EGPWS (Honeywell TM) or the Terrain Awareness and Warning System (TAWS) as defined in the regulations -- can't use a trademark in the regs.

The discussion in your link about "blockiness" when zooming in is a result of the database grid references.  To save memory space, the resolution of the world-wide terrain data varies based on terrain variation and it's relative hazard to flight operation.  There's greater resolution (smaller grid) near airports and in mountainous areas.

The A320 does have airborne radar that is capable of displaying "weather" which really means precipitation.  It can't be displayed at the same time as the terrain to avoid confusion.

Neither the EGPWS or the radar data are in the FMGS.  Their data is just underlayed on the navigation display.  (EGPWS does receive data from the FMGS to support it's warning functions.)

TAWS/EGPWS function is described in [TSO-C151c](https://skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/4189.pdf)

Comment: It just seemed confusing when you look at how the terrain display updates itself: it doesn't update visually by top to bottom, but instead, by radials of a circle (just like weather radar)...

Comment: That's a consequence of designing the system to the least common denominator.  When Allied Signal (now Honeywell) designed the EGPWS in the mid 90's, a major criteria was that it had to be retrofitable into the majority of the fleet.  A big issue was the availability of a display for the data.  Since almost all had a dedicated weather radar display the decision was to 'share' the display.  That meant using the same physical interface to the display (via an external switch) and data format.  As a result, the terrain data is drawn in the same manner as the radar displays the weather.